# What does Grievous mean?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

> Anakin: All the escape pods have been launched.
>
> OBI-WAN: **Grievous**.
>
> Anakin: Can you fly a cruiser like this?
>
> Obi-Wan: You mean, do I know how to land what's left of this thing?

What does Grievous mean? Is Obi-Wan referring to General Grievous (or) English word Grievous?

Comment: I guess, we should interpret his remark as 'Grievous has launched all escape pods'

Comment: Or "It must be General Grievous's handiwork"

Comment: I prefer to consider as Obi-Wan saying the opposite of “Righteous.”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grievous launched the pods. Obi-Wan is referencing that event.

> He reached a hatch and opened it. His calculations were correct; he was in one of the escape-pod bays. He started for the pods, then hesitated. Why not make things a little harder for those annoying Jedi? **He crossed to the control panel and began flipping switches, jettisoning all the escape pods, row by row.**
>
> **Finally, only one pod remained. There, Grievous thought. Let’s see them get out of this!** He climbed into the last escape pod and blasted away from the remains of his command ship. There were Federation ships close enough to pick him up, and the clone fighters were too busy with his droids to worry about an unarmed escape pod. He had gotten away.
>
> ...
>
> “All the escape pods have been launched,” Anakin said as Obi-Wan joined him. **That has to be General Grievous’s work. If we’d only been a little faster, we’d have had him!**
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

In the [graphic novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_%E2%80%94_Revenge_of_the_Sith), we see Grievous entering a pod, overlaid with Obi-Wan's dialogue.

> [image]